# Oracle - Convert Hourly Data from Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, pivot, transpose

I have an Oracle table filled with rows of data associated to datetimes.

EX:

```
Value     Datetime
-----     ----------------
123       12/08/2018 00:00
456       12/08/2018 01:00
789       12/08/2018 02:00
...       ...
312       12/08/2018 23:00
321       12/09/2018 00:00
...       ...
```

I need to take this data and group it by day, but somehow transpose the hourly data to columns with one column for each hour in a 24 hour period.

EX:

```
Date          Value(00:00)     Value(01:00)     Value(02:00)     ...     Value(23:00) 
----          ------------     ------------     ------------     ---     ------------
12/08/2018    123              456              789              ...     312
12/09/2018    321              654              987              ...     423
...           ...              ...              ...              ...     ...
```

What is the most effective way of querying to obtain the data from the table in this format?  I apologize if this question has already been answered.  I've searched a good bit online, but I'm honestly somewhat at odds of even knowing the right keywords to search for this answer.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simplify the answer the best I could for stack overflow.  I was able to get the information formatted using a query similar to the one below.

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) >= 0 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) < 1  THEN value ELSE 0 END) as "value(00:00)",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) >= 1 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) < 2  THEN value ELSE 0 END) as "value(01:00)",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) >= 2 AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) < 3  THEN value ELSE 0 END) as "value(02:00)",
                ...
       FROM (
            SELECT TO_CHAR(datetime,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date,
                   value,
                   datetime
            FROM table
       )
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

The process of taking rows and turning them into columns is called *pivoting*. As of 11g (?), Oracle has the `PIVOT` keyword to do this natively. Note there is no "time" datatype in Oracle, so I converted them to two-digit characters before pivoting. There must be an aggregate function in the pivot, so make sure you do not have duplicate rows with the same date.

```
select * from (
  select "Value", to_char( "Datetime", 'HH24' ) as dt from table1
)
pivot ( max( "Value" ) for ( dt ) in ( '00' AS "hour0", 
    '01' as "hour1", '02' as "hour2" ));
```

**Edit:**

To aggregate by the day, ignoring the time component, add a `TRUNCed` column to the inline view.

```
select * from (
  select "Value", trunc("Datetime") as the_day, 
         to_char( "Datetime", 'HH24' ) as dt from table1
)
pivot ( max( "Value" ) for ( dt ) in ( '00', '01', '02' ));
```

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af654/1)

Comment: Cool.  This is actually a really elegant solution for this problem.  Is there a good way to divide the datetimes up by day.  Ie, have a row for 12/8/18,  a row for 12/9/18, a row for 12/10/18, and so on with the values for the hours of the day still listed as columns?